ag grid: possible to customize when cells flash?
enableCellChangeFlash is used to flash cells that get updated content.
However, Im using valueFormatters on a couple of columns and I only want to flash the cell contents if the rendered content changes instead of the underlying value.
Example: I have prices which are floats, e.g.: 3.2321393. I fix this to 2 decimals (.e.g; 3.23) . Now I only want to flash the cell if the rendered value changes, say 3.24, but not when the underlying value changes, say 3.23214 without a visible change.
Is this possible?

@ViqMontana's answer pointed in the right direction, but would require calling flashCells for every cell that needed updating.
Instead I've ported the code in the equals function that can optionally be passed to a column definition.
// Equals function to check if cell value has *visibly* changed. Only then the cell will flash
function equalsCellFN(valueA, valueB) {
  const valueFormatter = this.valueFormatter;
  const newFormattedValue = valueFormatter ? valueFormatter({ value: valueA }) : valueA;
  const oldFormattedValue = valueFormatter ? valueFormatter({ value: valueB }) : valueB;
  return oldFormattedValue === newFormattedValue
}


What I'd recommend doing is setting enableCellChangeFlash to false then using the onCellValueChanged callback to see if the new value has changed after the valueFormatter has been applied, and if it has changed, then using the api method flashCells to flash the cells.
Here is what your onCellValueChanged would look like:
  onCellValueChanged: function (params) {
    const valueFormatter = params.column.getColDef().valueFormatter;
    const newFormattedValue = valueFormatter
      ? valueFormatter({ value: params.newValue })
      : params.newValue;
    const oldFormattedValue = valueFormatter
      ? valueFormatter({ value: params.oldValue })
      : params.newValue;
    if (newFormattedValue != oldFormattedValue) {
      // Flash the cell
      params.api.flashCells({
        rowNodes: [params.node],
        columns: [params.column],
      });
    }
  },

Demo

Ah nice makes sense. Slightly concerned that this would potentially result in flashCells being called quite a few times almost concurrently. Not sure if that works as intended.

you can bulkify the code by passing in a list of row nodes and columns to flashCells once your changes have been applied.

Well that wouldn't work since all rows could have different cells in need of highlighting. I'll try your option anyway. Will leave this open for a couple more days to source other interest

you gave me the right direction. See my answer. Points are yours
